# Are Humans Considered Keystone species?

Tags: ecology

Do humans have a huge impact on the ecosystem ? is it possible for other animals to live without us ?

Comment: Welcome to Biology! Homework questions are welcomed, but it should be accompanied by some evidence of research effort before it will be considered.

Comment: @Remi.b - Someone has undermined my authority with a brilliant answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am voting to close as homework question.

I felt like I would give you a few hints though.

> is it possible for other animals to live without us?

Life on earth have existed for almost 4 billions years. Animals have existed for about 600 millions years. Modern human ([AMHS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anatomically_modern_humans)) have existed for 0.2 million years.

> Do humans have a huge impact on the ecosystem?

Here are just a few pictures taken by airplane of agricultural lands

[image] [image]

[image]

and a koala searching its home after a rapid man-made deforestation

[image]

Comment: I like the aerial pics but they don't show animals :)

Comment: ha ha I inverted the OP questions though. I fixed it. The pictures were there to adresse the question of whether human affect their ecosystem (not talking about animals specifically). But I added a picture of Koala just for you @AliceD

Comment: oh no, not a remi-alone-in-the-world koala.... That is so sad.... I nearly not +1'd because of this painful addition

Comment: I call BS. The photo has clearly been cropped to hide the vast koala paradise of eucalyptus and...and...what else do koalas like? anything? ...just above the frame.

Comment: @Corvus yes maybe. This (and other similar) picture went kinda viral in the past weeks. If it was to be true that the koala was living at this exact location before, then it was probably not too far away during the deforestation and therefore, there must be some green stuff not too far outside the frame of the picture anyway.

Comment: @Remi.b, I'm just kidding of course. The koala picture is a nice touch in this great answer!